# Sending data to onSensorChanged given that the SensorEvent constructor is not visible

Tags: android, testing, sensors

I'm trying to write a service to test a class which implements `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` by passing it data I can generate as if it were coming from the sensor. The problem I've run into is that I cannot create my own SensorEvent objects to pass the function as SensorEvent has no public constructors. I tried creating my own class which would have the needed functionality of SensorEvent and casting it but have since discovered that to be able to cast, it would need to be a sublcass and to subclass it I'd need to be able to access the constructor.

Is there any other way to create an object which I can pass in place of the SensorEvent or is there a better approach to simulating the missing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The [SensorSimulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) project probably does the testing you're trying to do.  But if not, it should have some code that may help